# Unreliable results using quotes with variables in windows batch for loop

Tags: windows, variables, for-loop, batch-file

I'm running a for loop to go through a list of services to stop, but I'm having trouble with the quotes, and rather unusual results as well.

```
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ('wmic service where ^(displayname like "%%tsm%%"^) get name ^| findstr "TSM"') do echo "%%a"
```

My results are with this:

```
"Service Name
"Service Name
```

If I switch to:

```
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ('wmic service where ^(displayname like "%%tsm%%"^) get name ^| findstr "TSM"') do echo ""%%a""
```

The results are:

```
""Service Name
""Service Name
```

And, if I switch to:

```
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ('wmic service where ^(displayname like "%%tsm%%"^) get name ^| findstr "TSM"') do echo ^"%%a^"
```

The results:

```
"Service Name
"Service Name
```

Obviously something is happening that I don't understand, because I simply cannot get it to encapsulate my results in quotes so I can run commands such as net stop or sc delete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ('wmic service where ^(displayname like "%%tsm%%"^) get name ^| findstr "TSM"') do (
for /f "delims=" %%i in ("%%a") do echo "%%i"
)
```

this is due to the "end of line" sign of wmic (`CRLFCR`).

Comment: Wow, awesome.  Can I ask how you discovered that?

Comment: Some other programs from the Unix World use this technic. I found the solution on `dostips.com`.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I can't upvote because of my new account, but if I could I would!